# Capybara/Cucumber not finding flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm having trouble getting Cucumber / Capybara to find a 'success' flash message on a page after a user is logged in.  I'm able to see the message if I do it manually in the browser, so I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong in my steps.

#### user_login.feature

```
Feature: User login 

  Scenario: A user successfully logs in from the homepage
    Given A user is on the homepage
    When the user clicks "Login"                                                     
    And they fill out the form
    Then they should see a success message
```

#### step_definition

```
Given /^A user is on the homepage$/ do
  @user = Factory.create(:user)
  visit root_path
end

When /^the user clicks "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  click_link arg1
end 

When /^they fill out the form$/ do
  fill_in "email", with: @user.email
  fill_in "password", with: "blahblah1"
  click_button "Sign in"                                                             
end

Then /^they should see a success message$/ do
  page.should have_selector ".alert", text: "Logged in!"
end
```

#### output

```
expected css ".alert" with text "Logged in!" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, I made a **DERP**.  The credentials I was using (password) to fill in the form weren't the same as the user I was creating via FactoryGirl.  This was causing an 'invalid email / password' message to appear when I was testing for a 'success' message.

To debug what the page was outputting, I added a `page.should have_content "asdfsdfas"` in my spec.  When the test fails, Cucumber outputs the content it got on the page compared to what you expected it to receive.

Comment: +1, for letting me know about: `page.should have_selector ".alert", text: "Logged in!"` (the text: thing) :)

Comment: A useful thing to remember for future work is that the Capybara command "save_and_open_page" will save the current page as a file, and open it in your default browser. This command is perfect for figuring out what's going on when your test isn't working how you expect.

Comment: also just `puts body` to keep it simple